# Set value to Datepicker and Listpicker from SQLITE DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am writing code for fetching the data from the SQLITE database to the Controls those added on the Windows Phone Application page.
In my page there is one TextBox, DatePicker & Listpicker, from SQLITE query I am getting data but it only shows in the TextBox field only, not shown in other controls like DatePicker and ListPicker.

Xaml CODE:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Name="dpkDate" Margin="0,144,0,332" />
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="priority" Margin="10,233,10,188" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" Background="#FFF7EBEB" SelectedIndex="2">
    <ListBoxItem x:Name="high" Content="High" Foreground="Black"/>
    <ListBoxItem x:Name="medium" Content="Medium" Foreground="Black"/>
    <ListBoxItem x:Name="low" Content="Low" Foreground="Black"/>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="287" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Name="TaskListBox" Margin="10,302,-10,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Wrpite Note" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Name="TextField"/>
```

.cs code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
    // Create the table Task, if it doesn't exist.
    dbConn.CreateTable<Task>();
    // Retrieve the task list from the database.

    try
    {
        string id = NavigationContext.QueryString["selectedItem"].ToString();
        //string note = NavigationContext.QueryString["selectedItem.Text"].ToString();
        //MessageBox.Show(id); //this retrive the index of selected item and display in message

        var note= dbConn.Query<Task>("select * from task where Id='" + id + "'").FirstOrDefault();
        if (note == null)
            MessageBox.Show("Note Not Present in DataBase");
        else
        {
            TextField.Text = note.Text;
            dpkDate.Value = DateTime.Parse(note.Text);
            ((ListBoxItem)priority.SelectedItem).Content = note.Text;
        //     Date = dpkDate.Value.Value.ToString(),
        //Text = TextField.Text,
        //Priority=((ListBoxItem)priority.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(), //here have to make change to get 

        }

    }
    catch { }
    // Create the database connection.

}
```

Where I am wrong? Please help.
Note:  "http://prntscr.com/44sbux" you can see screenshot here, I can't indent so posted screenshot here.

As per request: Structure of class Task
// Task class representing the Task table. Each attribute in the class become one attribute in the database.

```
public sealed class Task
{
    /// <summary>
    /// You can create an integer primary key and let the SQLite control it.
    /// </summary>
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Date { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public String Priority { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "------------------------------------\n "+ Id +"\n" + Date + "\n" + Text + " \n " + Priority + " \n------------------------------------ ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your TextField.Text value

Comment: What's the structure of class `Task`? Why are you assigning `note.Text` to each control?

Comment: I updated the question with structure of class Task,
I am assigning the note.text because in note it shows all the details of selecteditem,
For more details can you join me teamviewer and check code

Comment: TextField.Text shows only Note from the seleted item of ListBox

Comment: Teamviewer ID 944 847 769
Password: 8933